# why #include only complete declarations and definitions?

Tags: c++, header-files, declaration, definition

Mr. Bjarne Stroustrup says in his book "The C++ Programming Language Fourth Edition" on the middle of page 425 (§15.2.2):

> It is wise not to be too clever about the use of #include. My recommendations are:
>   ...
>   include only complete declarations and definitions.

I can not understand what does he mean? 
I see lots of codes which use .h files for the declarations and .cpp files for definitions and then just include .h files.
so what does he mean exactly by the recommendation?

Comment: Structures and classes are *also* defined, often in header files. As are usually templates and inline functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question via email from the author (Bjarne Stroustrup) of the book to make sure about his meaning.
He responded:

> Consider:

```
#define X foo
#include "essentials.h"

// ... the rest goes here

};
```

where essentials.h is

```
class X {

    X();

    X(const X& a);

    X(X&&);

    // ... and more ...
```

> The result of such "cleverness", spreading a definition across several files leads to unmaintainable messes.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand Stroustrup correctly, these are "complete" declarations:

```
// foo.h
void foo();
struct S {
    int bar() const;
};
```

These are "incomplete" declarations, and you shouldn't write headers like these:

```
// bar_start.h
struct Bar {

// bar_end.h
};
```

Do:

```
#include "foo.h"
```

Don't:

```
#include "bar_start.h"
void foo();  // foo is a member of Bar
#include "bar_end.h"
```

Comment: @user463035818 Headers are meant to be included, so I don't really see the difference.

Comment: I'm really struggling to imagine a reason for wanting to write terrible code like that. It seems so obvious to me that you shouldn't do that so I was also confused by the quote.